# hibernate multiple records update in a single statement

Tags: hibernate, row

I have table and want to update each Salary record for each ID

```
ID      FirstName     Salary
10      A             10,000
15      B             5000
17      C             7000
19      D             8000
```

But  what happening is update statement is executed for each row.Suppose I have 1000 records then update statement is executing 1000 times.Is there any better way I can achive this.
I am doing as ,

```
RetriveDataMethod()
{ 
List listIdSalary = retriveIdAndSalary();
Iterator itr =listIdSalary.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()){
   Object[] idStr = (Object[]) itr.next();
   String id = (String)idStr[0];
   String salary = (String)idStr[1];
   updateDataMethod(id,salary)
 }
}

updateDataMethod(String id,String salary)
{
String s = "update table set salary=:salry where id=:id"
Query q = session.createQuery(s);
q.setString("salary",salary);
q..setString("id",id);
q.executeUpdate();
session.commit();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do everything using Criteria and/or HQL/JPAQL statements, you will allow Hibernate to cache up those statements.  This way when the session is flushed or committed it will issue all your update statements then, which is more efficient.

You might also want to question whether doing a commit() after each update is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks@robertvoliva                                                Can you please explain a bit more .."This way when the session is flushed or committed it will issue all your update statements "

Comment: It will still issue 1000 update statements, but it will do so using the same database connection and transaction.  You won't go through the overhead of connecting to the database and starting/committing a transaction 1000 times, just once.

Comment: Thanks again @robertvoliva . In my code then where i can write session.commit() and also do I need to change code sothat same session,same transaction will be used for 1000 records.(it will not create new for every 1000 records)

Comment: A simple first step would be to place it outside the while loop in your RetriveDataMethod.

Comment: if I put updateDataMethod() outside while loop from RetriveDataMethod() then I am not able to get each ids and each salary.

Comment: Don't move the updateDataMethod.  Simply move the session.commit() line from the updateDataMethod to outside the while loop.

Comment: there is no while loop in updateDataMethod() whatever id and salary I am getting that I seperated in RetriveDataMethod() using while loop and passing to updateDataMethod()

Comment: RetriveDataMethod()
{ 
List listIdSalary = retriveIdAndSalary();
Iterator itr =listIdSalary.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()){
   Object[] idStr = (Object[]) itr.next();
   String id = (String)idStr[0];
   String salary = (String)idStr[1];
   updateDataMethod(id,salary)
 }
 session.commit();
}

updateDataMethod(String id,String salary)
{
String s = "update table set salary=:salry where id=:id"
Query q = session.createQuery(s);
q.setString("salary",salary);
q..setString("id",id);
q.executeUpdate();
}

Comment: ok.I will try this.is there any better approach sothat I can optimize performance ? I mean how to avoid 1000 update statements :(